# CodeIgniter 4 - Can't insert my int data into my database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-4

I have my input inside my form, and I could get all the data into the controller.

My Form inside the view

```
<form action="/arsip/save" method="post">
                <?= csrf_field(); ?>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="nama_pemegang_hak" class="form-label">Nama Pemegang Hak</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nama_pemegang_hak" class="form-control <?= $validation->hasError('nama_pemegang_hak') ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" id=" nama_pemegang_hak" value="<?= old('nama_pemegang_hak'); ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label class="form-label" for="nama_hak">Nama Hak</label>
                    <select class="form-select" id="nama_hak" name="nama_hak">
                        <option value="Hak Milik">Hak Milik</option>
                        <option value="Hak Guna Bangunan">Hak Guna Bangunan</option>
                        <option value="Warkah">Warkah</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="nomor_hak" class="form-label">Nomor Hak</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nomor_hak" class="form-control <?= $validation->hasError('nomor_hak') ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" id="nomor_hak" value="<?= old('nomor_hak'); ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="kelurahan" class="form-label">Kelurahan</label>
                    <input type="text" name="kelurahan" class="form-control <?= $validation->hasError('kelurahan') ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" id="kelurahan" value="<?= old('kelurahan'); ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="kecamatan" class="form-label">Kecamatan</label>
                    <input type="text" name="kecamatan" class="form-control <?= $validation->hasError('kecamatan') ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" id="kecamatan" value="<?= old('kecamatan'); ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="no_lemari" class="form-label">Nomor Lemari</label>
                    <input type="number" name="no_lemari" min="1" class="form-control <?= $validation->hasError('no_lemari') ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" id="no_lemari" value="<?= old('no_lemari'); ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="no_rak" class="form-label">Nomor Rak</label>
                    <input type="number" name="no_rak" min="1" class="form-control <?= $validation->hasError('no_rak') ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" id="no_rak" value="<?= old('no_rak'); ?>">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

All the data is going to be collected inside my controller. After it went pass the validation (it's just required and is_unique for the validation), the data is going to be saved inside the database. Everything went well except that the data from no_lemari and no_rak is not saved into the database (in the database, it only put the number 0 even though my input is not 0).

Controller code to save into database

```
$this->bukuModel->save([
            'nama_pemegang_hak' => $this->request->getVar('nama_pemegang_hak'),
            'nama_hak' => $this->request->getVar('nama_hak'),
            'nomor_hak' => $this->request->getVar('nomor_hak'),
            'kelurahan' => $this->request->getVar('kelurahan'),
            'kecamatan' => $this->request->getVar('kecamatan'),
            'no_lemari' => intval($this->request->getVar('no_lemari')),
            'no_rak' => intval($this->request->getVar('no_rak'))
        ]);

        session()->setFlashdata('pesan', 'Data berhasil ditambahkan.');

        return redirect()->to('/arsip/home');
```

I used intval to change the data type into int (it works when I use dd to check it), but the value inside the database is still 0. I tried doing this

```
$nomor_lemari = $this->request->getVar('no_lemari');
$nomor_rak = intval($this->request->getVar('no_rak'));
```

and changing the code in the save into this

```
'no_lemari' => $nomor_lemari,
'no_rak' => $nomor_rak
```

but nothing really changes as well. Can anyone tell me what is wrong and what do I need to change?

My table structure

[image: my database table]

Comment: what does your table structure look like?

Comment: @Adi I added the table structure on the question

Comment: **Just a note:** Next time translate your source code to English when requesting help on StackOverflow. Otherwise, most of us won't be able to provide any constructive feedback.  [Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange/13684#13684)

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa oh alright, I'm sorry. I was thinking it's probably not a problem since it was mostly just variable names, but I get what you are saying.

Comment: Dos your bukuModel have no_lemari and no_rak in the `$allowedFields` array?

Comment: @SimonWeber ah you are right... I forgot to put it in the allowedFields. I was so sure I put it already since I always put it in the model after adding it into the database but I guess I forgot this time. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Dragonarc Your welcome! This happened to me from time to time. So I made it a habit to check the $protectedFields array first when i encounter such problems like yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I can't find the the reason why the data keep being 0, I ended up removing the CI save method and saved my data in this way

```
$db = \Config\Database::connect();

    $nama_pemegang_hak = $this->request->getVar('nama_pemegang_hak');
    $nama_hak = $this->request->getVar('nama_hak');
    $nomor_hak = $this->request->getVar('nomor_hak');
    $kelurahan = $this->request->getVar('kelurahan');
    $kecamatan = $this->request->getVar('kecamatan');
    $no_lemari = (int) $this->request->getVar('no_lemari');
    $no_rak = (int) $this->request->getVar('no_rak');


    // Execute INSERT SQL query
    $db->query(
        "INSERT INTO buku (nama_pemegang_hak, nama_hak, nomor_hak, kelurahan, kecamatan, no_lemari, no_rak) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
        [$nama_pemegang_hak, $nama_hak, $nomor_hak, $kelurahan, $kecamatan, $no_lemari, $no_rak]
    );
```

For my update, I just added this line into my code

```
$db = \Config\Database::connect();
$db->query("UPDATE buku SET no_lemari = ?, no_rak = ? WHERE id = ?", [$no_lemari, $no_rak, $id]);
```

So the entire code turn into this

```
$no_lemari = (int)$this->request->getVar('no_lemari');
$no_rak = (int)$this->request->getVar('no_rak');

        $this->bukuModel->save([
            'id' => $id,
            'nama_pemegang_hak' => $this->request->getVar('nama_pemegang_hak'),
            'nama_hak' => $this->request->getVar('nama_hak'),
            'nomor_hak' => $this->request->getVar('nomor_hak'),
            'kelurahan' => $this->request->getVar('kelurahan'),
            'kecamatan' => $this->request->getVar('kecamatan'),
            'no_lemari' => $no_lemari,
            'no_rak' => $no_rak
        ]);

$db = \Config\Database::connect();
$db->query("UPDATE buku SET no_lemari = ?, no_rak = ? WHERE id = ?", [$no_lemari, $no_rak, $id]);
```

Well, so I basically just brute force the data save using the query. I still don't really understand the problem but forcefully updating the data worked so I'll just use this until anyone gave me a better answer